# Как получить из таблиц последнюю запись по сгенерированному идентификатору?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Как получить самую последнюю запись из таблицы?

Например, в таблице есть такие идентификаторы:

```
1
2
7
3
10
5
```

Последняя запись здесь с идентификатором 10.

Из известных составляющих выражения - это имя таблицы. При этом подразумеваем, что поиск нужен по первому столбцу который *Primary Key* и хранит идентификаторы.

Иденитификатор для каждой таблицы создается триггером, который при вставке записи формирует Id для этой записи. Имена колонок с идентификатором отличаются и заранее неизвестны, поэтому запрос вообще не должен быть привязан к именам колонок.
Идентификаторы создаются последовательностями, где только `CYCLE_FLAG=N`.

Вот что я использую (меняю только имя таблицы):

```sql
select a.* from (
    select rownum rnum, MESSAGES.* 
    from MESSAGES
) a 
where rnum=(select count(1) from MESSAGES);
```

Пример работает и я получаю в ответ одну строку, которая иногда является записью с самым последним Id в таблице, а в некоторых таблицах этот запрос не выдает последнию  запись, как если бы первое поле таблицы не было отсортировано по порядку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если только первая колонка содержит идентификатор, то надо так:

```sql
select t.* 
from table_name t
order by 1 desc
fetch first row only;
```

---

Для версий <12.1 (опробовано на 11.2.0.4) попробуйте так:

```sql
with table_name as (
    select to_number (trim (column_value)) id, 'item '||rownum name
    from xmltable ('1,2,7,3,10,5')
)
-- здесь начинается запрос
select * from (
    select t.* 
    from table_name t 
    order by 1 desc
) where rownum = 1;
```

Результат:

```
        ID NAME       
---------- -----------
        10 item 5
```

PS Убедитесь, что используется опция NOCYCLE в генераторах последовательностей.

Comment: ('1,2,7,3,10,5') - неизвестная переменная , там сотни тысяч полей

Comment: Какая переменная? Каких полей? Что у вас не получается?

Comment: ('1,2,7,3,10,5')  - вот это что ? Как будет выглядеть мой код окончательно ? Я не понимаю зачем в коде эти числа ?  order by id desc - как я понимаю, это сортировка по возрастанию. Но вот имя (`id`) первого поля у разных таблиц - разное.

Comment: Это тестовые данные, чтобы показать, что запрос рабочий. А вы куда это вставили?

Comment: я не успел проверить,пока негде, я не понимаю где ставиться имя базы , если в скобках тестовые данные, то каков будет чистый запрос.

Comment: Ваш код начинается от `select * from (...`. Таблицу t надо заменить на вашу таблицу.  Вы же не предоставили тестовой таблицы в вопросе.

Comment: так я ищу универсальное решение, как я написал выше в примере, там я только меняю имя таблицы и все и этот запрос работает на всех таблицах, только меняю имя таблицы, но вот из некоторых он достает последнюю строку , а в некоторых берет из середины. Поэтому и спрашиваю как можно сделать по другому. Завтра попробую ваше решение. Спасибо.

Comment: Замените `from t` на `from your_table_name`, или как она у вас называется, id на your_id. И всё будет работать.

Comment: То есть все же я еще должен использовать имя первого столбца, а разве Oracle  не предусматривает встроенную команду, которая бы искала последний выданный id , опираясь  либо на  1-е по порядку поля и в дополнение на  то, что поле имеет тип Primary, так как таблицы  с которыми работаю построены по такому принципу. То есть чтобы максимум была одна неизвестная переменная и эта переменная - имя таблицы.

Comment: А, так вам имя первой колонки нужно, которая primary_key? Попробуйте поправить вопрос, чтобы он стал понятней. По возможности, с примером тестовых данных и желаемого результата.